# Visual Studio Code no me reconoce los archivos de javascript

Tags: javascript, vscode

En mis carpetas los archivos se guardan con la extensión .js , pero cuando lo quiero abrir en Visual Studio Code me toma el archivo como de texto pero no como de javascript.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. No mezcles etiquetas porque sí: **JavaScript != Java**, [visual] es una _meta-etiqueta_, y VS != VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

En la esquina inferior derecha debería salirte una opción para elegir el lenguaje, y luego te saldría un desplegable con una lista de lenguajes. Simplemente, eliges JavaScript.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy amable en responderme. Ha sido de gran ayuda,pude resolverlo . Gracias !!!

Comment: @VerónicaMartina dar las gracias en los comentarios no esta mal, pero si esta respuesta te solucionó el problema, [aceptala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En la parte inferior de VScode deberías tener una opción parecida a esta, supongamos que VScode te lo detecta como un texto sin formato

[image: opción texto sin formato]

cuando hagas click te debería salir un desplegable como este, seleccionas el lenguaje, en este caso JavaScript.

[image: desplegable]

Otro posible solución sería configurar manualmente la asociación, para ello ve a Archivo < Preferencias y busca "Files: Associations", agregas la extensión con su valor.

Debería quedar algo así en el archivo settings.json

```json
    "files.associations": {
    ".js": "javascript"
}
```

Puedes ver la referencia [aquí](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_file-associations).